# How to get Currently logged user's ID in pyrocms?

Tags: codeigniter, session, pyrocms

Now I have a project with `pyrocms`, I have a problem to get the current id user in module's controller, does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=pyrocms%20user_id => http://www.pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/629 => `$this->user->id;`

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
$this->current_user->id
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns `null` for me.
I know I'm logged in as on my template I'm echoing

```
{{ user:display_name }}
```

Just fine.

Oddness